Software to map the colors of an image on a 3d volume
Some time long ago, I used a program where you loaded an image and it extracted the colors from it and mapped them into an RGB cube.
It allowed me to change the viewpoint, so I made this animation:

Yup. I have no idea what the software was called or if it exists anymore.
Does anyone know any software that can do this?

There is a blog post (it's actually an Observable notebook with code) that explains the CIE Chromaticity diagram, and it has references to the RGB color cube. Maybe you can adapt the code snippets in that post? (I know not 100% on point so: comment rather than an answer

Ty. I'll take a look.

Interesting. Except for black pixels maybe. How does the program deal with multiple pixels of the same color?

Oh. I found it.
https://vicanek.de/imageprocessing/colorcube.htm
As it is an 8bf plug it is a bit complicated to run it, but Irfanview can run it.
I am leaving the question open to see if someone finds some program to do something similar.

Please accept your own answer.
